# How can I manipulate several hair strands instead of the whole hair?

Tags: hair

[image: hair strand]
I am diving into the hair particle system, but am a big noob so yeah..
What I want to achieve is basically this:

[image: strand examples]

However, whenever I manipulate my hair-system with the children's kink the the whole hair itself gets manipulated instead of several strands. Does someone know what I am doing wrong? An answer would be very generous :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use different kink settings for the hair then you need several `Particle Settings`. The settings always affect all strands made with a particular setting. So the trick is to use several settings and assign them to different areas.

In `Weight Paint` mode you can define `Vertex Groups`. (Use the <kbd>+</kbd> button to create a new group.) The in the Particle Settings you can assign these groups. The `Density` group restricts the area for the hair strands.

In the following example, there are two weight painted groups "Curl" and "Radial", and there are two hair particle settings (2 slots). The groups are assigned to the respective particle settings. The areas can even overlap if you want.

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you so much <3

Comment: Okey, well... I thought I got it by your description. but as it seems I am too dumb. I do completely understand the thing with the two particle settings, however when it comes to the density...          Basically when I control the density with the weight paint it doesnt make several strands but just reduces the amount of hair. So it gets thinner and thinner but there are no individual strands.

Comment: Basically you get about 18 curl strands on the right, while I get 1 big chunk of hair. (as seen above). I feel like the weight paint density thingy is only to get a transition between the 2 systems.

Comment: I've used 20 hair particles which are the base of the strand. (Emission -> Number, default value is 1000. You can add them also in the Particle Edit mode.) Each hair particle has 20 children (type Simple). This created the strands. If you increase the number of particles and their children's you will get one big chunk of hair.
Weight paint defines the area. If the area gets bigger you want to increase the number of particles or add more in P.Edit mode so that the density stays the same.

Comment: The type "Interpolated" of the hair children can also change the appearance because it spreads hair in a different way over the weight painted area. "Simple" makes them look more clumpy. Play around with the radius setting. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Ahhh, now it works.Thank you so so much for the  answers. I really appreciate it!